# Update.train from caret generating wrong length of vector prediction

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to update a model trained using method `rpart` in `caret` using `update` and trying to predict from new data. This is my code for making a model

```
# Loading the package
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(solubility)
library(caret)
library(rpart)

# Data Prep
MWTr <- subset(solTrainXtrans, select='MolWeight') # dim(MWTr) yields 951,1
MWTe <- subset(solTestXtrans, select='MolWeight')  # dim(MWTe) yields 316,1

# Training
trCtrl <- trainControl(method='cv')
cpTune <- train(MWTr, solTrainY,
                method='rpart',
                trControl=ctrl)
```

When I predict using the `cpTune` model with new data, there is no problem. The following code does not yield any problem

```
pred <- predict(cpTune, solTestXtrans) # length(pred) is 316
```

But when I update `cpTune` model with different `cp` parameter, it yields a problem

```
# Update
cpTune1 <- update(cpTune, param=list(cp=0.5))
pred1 <- predict(cpTune, solTestXtrans) # length(pred) is 951
```

This is the warning message

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 316 rows but variables found have 951 rows
```

I tried with formula but didn't work as well. Here is the code I tried

```
MWTr <- data.frame(MolWeight=solTrainXtrans$Molweight,
                   Y=solTrainY)
MWTe <- data.frame(MolWeight=solTestXtrans$MolWeight)
cpTune <- train(Y~MolWeight, data=MWTr,
                method='rpart',
                trControl=trCtrl)
# predicting using cpTune works well
cpTune1 <- update(cpTune, param=list(cp=0.5))
predict(cpTune1, MWTe) # yields same problem as above
```

Why the model after update produce a vector with same length as the predict from data frame used for training before the update?

This is my session info:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK:     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rpart_4.1-13                    caret_6.0-81                   
[3] ggplot2_3.1.0                   lattice_0.20-35                
[5] AppliedPredictiveModeling_1.1-7
```

Comment: You have a typo in your example that may be material.  You define `trCtrl`, but then you reference some other object not defined in your example: `trControl=ctrl)`.  I changed it to `trControl=trCtrl)` and I get 316 observations in both cases.  Please check your code in a fresh R session with no existing objects.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp Hey thanks for the comment. That must have been a typo. I checked the code again in my R, it was `trCtrl` instead of `ctrl`. I tried again just in case with a new R session but still causing the same error as shown in the post :/

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the odd behavior so don't think I can help.